# Jenkins Pipeline environment issue

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

Hi i have a following jenkins pipeline like below.

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  environment {

 //JSON_NAME = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "sed -n '2 p' package.json | awk '{print \$2}' | sed 's/\\,//g'").trim()
   JSON_NAME = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "sed -n '2 p' package.json | awk '{print \$2}' | sed 's/\\,//g' | awk -F "/" '{print \$2}'").trim()          
}
stages {
  stage ('Update Italy.json') {
     when {expression { fileExists('italy.json')}}
     steps {
        sh "echo ${JSON_NAME}"  
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

As you can see i have to env in ENVIRONMENT block.
First one is commented, and its working.

But when i try use my second ENV it gives me error.

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.div() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [ '{print $2}']
```

I couldnt figure out what wrong with this env. Any ideas ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try changing `awk -F "/"` to `awk -F '/'` i.e., single quote around delimiter

Comment: new error.
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Node_multi-branch_loban@tmp/durable-30e1ed50/script.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Comment: Are you sure there are no missing opening/closing quotes introduced anywhere in the line? Can you paste the updated command?

Comment: Yes sure. Here is updated command.
JSON_NAME = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "sed -n '2 p' package.json | awk '{print \$2}' | sed 's/\\,//g' | awk -F '/' '{print \$2}'").trim()

Comment: This looks fine. Such error messages can be confusing at times. You may need to check for missing quotes few lines above this line and see if there's any line that's introducing this error message.

Comment: If i run it in bash it works. And probably problem in the last part with awk -F command.
Because when i delete id it works normally.

Comment: I'm sorry. That's all i can suggest. Similar syntax worked for me in the past.